# Any other suggestions for adding blank dates?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, null

Optional with date. For this reason, I want to save it as null if it is empty. Normally it is accepted when I enter NULL from MSQL server program. But it doesn't happen with coding. I applied the following method. but there must be a simpler way. If anyone knows, I would be happy.

```
try {
    Harcama u = (Harcama) t; // t yi Uye formatına çevirdim

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

    if (u.getBitis() == null) {
        SQLQuery insertQuery = session.createSQLQuery("INSERT INTO Harcama (turId,altId,basl,nott,harcananTL) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");

        insertQuery.setParameter(0, u.getTurId());
        insertQuery.setParameter(1, u.getAltId());
        insertQuery.setParameter(2, u.getBasl());
        insertQuery.setParameter(3, u.getNott());
        insertQuery.setParameter(4, u.getHarcananTl());
        insertQuery.executeUpdate();

        session.getTransaction().commit();

        sonuc=true;

        Gnl.MesajVer.Sonuc("Kayıt ekleme işlemi başarı ile Tamamlandı");

    } else {
        SQLQuery insertQuery = session.createSQLQuery("INSERT INTO Harcama (turId,altId,basl,bitis,nott,harcananTL) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");

        insertQuery.setParameter(0, u.getTurId());
        insertQuery.setParameter(1, u.getAltId());
        insertQuery.setParameter(2, u.getBasl());
        insertQuery.setParameter(3, u.getBitis());
        insertQuery.setParameter(4, u.getNott());
        insertQuery.setParameter(5, u.getHarcananTl());
        insertQuery.executeUpdate();
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        sonuc=true;

        Gnl.MesajVer.Sonuc("Kayıt ekleme işlemi başarı ile Tamamlandı");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set null value in the `SQLQuery` parameter you need to provide its type, so you can get rid of `if/else` statement:

```
Harcama u = (Harcama) t; // t yi Uye formatına çevirdim

Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

SQLQuery insertQuery = session.createSQLQuery("INSERT INTO Harcama (turId,altId,basl,bitis,nott,harcananTL) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");

insertQuery.setParameter(0, u.getTurId());
insertQuery.setParameter(1, u.getAltId());
insertQuery.setParameter(2, u.getBasl());
// insertQuery.setParameter(3, u.getBitis(), new DateType()); // indicate hibernate type for nullable value
insertQuery.setParameter(3, u.getBitis(), StandardBasicTypes.DateType); // or use the type listed in Hibernate type registry
insertQuery.setParameter(4, u.getNott());
insertQuery.setParameter(5, u.getHarcananTl());
insertQuery.executeUpdate();
transaction.commit();

sonuc = true;

Gnl.MesajVer.Sonuc("Kayıt ekleme işlemi başarı ile Tamamlandı");
```